# .Jar won't finish my OpenDialog Command

Tags: java, swing, bufferedreader, fileopendialog

Hey guys one of the aspects of a program of mine opens .txt files via the OpenDialog javax command.  My bufferedreader works fine in my developing environment but when I try to export the project to a .jar my program doesn't seem to load in the data.  I can still access the openDialog subview, pick the file, etc. but the file won't load and I'm not sure how to debug a jar so I'm unsure on whether the error is a bufferedreader or from the dialog itself.  Like I said the program works fine when I compile and run BLueJ but for some reason when I create the .jar it stops after opendialog.  Anyone familiar with this type of error?

For explanation, the method adds a deck of cards from a text file already shuffled.
Card is declared as an ArrayList

```
        card.clear();
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        try
        {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;
            while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                card.add(line);
                displayField.append("\nAdded a " + line);
            }
            displayField.append("\nDeck Size:  " + card.size());
            breader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + filename + "'");  
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: OP has been edited.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        try
        {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
```

You need to specify a path.  You are getting the filename of the selected file, but disregarding the path.  In this case, `FileReader` will use the current working directory of your process as the file path.

Try this...

```
File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

... then you can ...

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(selectedFile);
```

Comment: Yup 100%.  I thought because it traced the path in BlueJ that the filename string would include the path but evidently not.  Props to you